# Ignore mysql error messages when executing an sql file

Tags: mysql

I am copying records from one table to another and there is a chance that some records may already be in the second table i am copying the records to.

Since there are lots of rows i am copying,i am looking a way to ignore all the record already exists messages from mysql and continue executing the mysql file.

Is there a way i can suppress the error messages?.

Comment: I dont want to insert duplicate records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [`INSERT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html):

> The [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) statement supports the following modifiers:
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Comment: See also [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/548570)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
zcat db.sql.gz | sed -e 's/INSERT/INSERT IGNORE/' | mysql -u user -p dbname
```